# Delete n lines after the first match in sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file.txt that contains the following

```
test 1
test 2
test 3
test 1
test 5
test 6
```

I want to use sed to delete 2 lines after the first match of "test 1", so the end result of file.txt looks like:

```
test 1
test 5
test 6
```

I know that I can delete 2 lines after a match using the command

```
sed -i '/test 1/,+2d' file.txt
```

but this will apply for all matches of "test 1", and the resulting file.txt will be empty.
How do I do this only for the first match?

Comment: Don't use `sed`, use something more programmable like `awk`.

Comment: @Barmar I don't mind using awk too. Any idea how to formulate the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with `awk`.

When you match the first `test 1`, set a variable and skip the next N lines with `getline`.

Print the line unconditionally once the variable is set.

```
awk -v nlines=2 '
    found {print; next} 
    /test 1/ { found = 1; for (i = 0; i < nlines; i++) getline }' file.txt
```

Comment: My example is a minimum working example. Is there a more concise way to write this command if I what I need is to delete 150 lines after first match?

Comment: You can put the `getline` calls in a `for` loop. `for (i = 0; i < 150; i++) getline`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `awk` to get this job done without using `getline`:

```
awk -v n=2 -v s="test 1" '!d && $0 == s{d = FNR + n} FNR > d' file
```

```
test 1
test 5
test 6
```

You can pass your patter in command line variable `s` and pass desired # of lines to be deleted in variable `n`.